# How to search in blob binary wise, and how to export data binary wise

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench, blob

I've a table with a blob field for each row.
The blob contains binary data, which can be represented as bytes or text ( using mysql workbench - open value in viewer)

1. Does anybody know how can I search specific sequence of bytes in a given bytes chunk(blob field),
   for example search for the sequence of bytes: 00 38 a7 in blob's binary representation
2. Is there any possibility to export all table values to csv with blob values in binary representation When I tried to export using mysql workbench I got for each blob ... as a value in csv.

Answer (score 1):

One way...

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE HEX(blob_col) REGEXP '(..)*0038A7';
```

The `(..)*` skips over any number of pairs of the hex digits.

For dumping, see `mysqldump --hex-blob` (not good for csv)

See `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`

Comment: Does that read the whole blob into memory?

Comment: @EvanCarroll - Blobs are read in whole, regardless of whether you use `LEFT(...)` or anything else that one would think could do a shortcut.